# Javascript empty value control

Tags: javascript, jquery

The if(usern == "") part of code is working. But when i pushed space button on keyboard for "input", it goes to else statement. How can i fix this?

```
usern = $("input").val();

if(usern == "")
        //don't do 
else 
        //do something
```

Comment: `$.trim()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to remove the white space from the value first:

```
var usern = $.trim($("input").val());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$.trim` utility function:

```
var usern = $.trim( $("input").val() );
```

Answer (score 3):

[**jQuery.trim()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):

```
if ( $.trim( usern ) === "" ) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

use `usern = $("input").val().trim();`

Comment: older browsers don't have `.trim()` - it either has to be shimmed, or use the one built into jQuery